# How to post JSON request via volley with header?

Tags: android, json, post, kotlin, android-volley

I tried to post JSON request via Volley and getting error **BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500**
This API URL tested ok in POSTMAN and can be called by IOS version app.

I suspect is headers value did not add in my code (correct me if Im wrong)

I tried to add in `getHeaders()` function in my code but seems like not working. Can someone to show me how to solve this?

**POSTMAN RESULT** 
[image]

Here is my current code:-

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.clipped_product_page)
        setTitle("Clipped Product")
        val actionbar = supportActionBar

        actionbar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        actionbar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        val URL = "https://api.sample.com/Api/user_id"

        val json = JSONObject()
        json.put("user_id", "1")
        json.put("code", "AB")

        val jsonOblect = object : JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                URL,
                json,
                Response.Listener {response ->
                    // Get your json response and convert it to whatever you want.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "You Clicked: $response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                },
                Response.ErrorListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error $it .message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        ) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json")
                return headers
            }
        }

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonOblect)

    }
```

How can I achieve this and convert my output to an array list?

Please help thank you.

Comment: This may help you https://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/  and response code 500 is server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request

Comment: show how you tried with `getHeaders()`. So far your code has nothing about headers.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Sorry for missed out. After I tried Mahdi solution still not working. You may check for above edited sample code.

Comment: ok, I see now. You are for some strange reason putting the user id and code into JSONObject insttead of sending them as post parameters as in postman, Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem by using sample code as below:-

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.clipped_product_page)
        setTitle("Clipped Product")
        val actionbar = supportActionBar

        actionbar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        actionbar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        val URL = "https://api.sample.com/Api/user_id"

        val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                Response.Listener { response -> Toast.makeText(this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() },
                Response.ErrorListener { error -> Toast.makeText(this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }) {
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params["user_id"] = "7"
                params["code"] = "MY"

                return params
            }

        }

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
}
```

I changed **JsonObjectRequest to StringRequest**

Answer (score 3):

To send a **post** request with Volley

```java
String URL = "";

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("email", "abc@abc.com");
json.put("password", "");
json.put("user_type", "");

 JsonObjectRequest jsonOblect = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, json, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
             // Get your json response and convert it to whatever you want.
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
          @Override
          public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Error
          }
    }) {
          @Override
          public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
             final Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
             headers.put("Authorization", "TOKEN");//put your token here
             return headers;
          }
};

VolleyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonOblect);
```

Comment: Hi @Mahdi-Malv, thanks for your help. But I tried to apply your code it still not working, any idea? I edited sample code and postman result above